# The Loader loads first but the site is not fully loaded at the back

Tags: javascript, performance

Issue is this the loader loads it self to 100 but the site not load at the back which make the screen stuck at 100 when the site get loaded the loader is removed

I need help in this case that loader completes itself t[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ4pl.png)o 100 when the site is completed loaded at the back

I try to compress the Images size n then try to make it load fast

Comment: It is imposible to know what you are doing without seeing code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.